# How do I get old versions of IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm learning from users that a site I'm working on has issues in IE9.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to replicate any of the issues they're seeing when I run IE10 in IE9 mode.

Is there a way to get my hands on and install old versions of IE for testing?  I found [this page,](http://www.oldapps.com/internet_explorer.php) which didn't help; I got a pop-up complaining that I already have IE9 installed.

Comment: Better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: There are some browser testing suites available, like IETester.

Comment: http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, neither IETester nor browserstack.com appears suitable.  The page in question fails on both of them in ways that my IE9 users aren't actually seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You can download virtual machines with old versions of Internet Explorer from Microsoft at:

http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools